# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: php

I have updated my MySQL Update code as it was not working correctly and I am now getting the below error message after pressing the update record button and trying to load the next page.

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in .... line 65

After I press the update asset button, I expect the asset display page to appear with a box confirming that it's been updated. It's just getting stuck on the update page and giving me the above error message and not loading the page as expected.

(asset = items we have)

My code is:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE assmgnt SET id = ?, name=?,manufacturer=?,model=?,description=?,type=?,size=?,consumable=?,serialnum=?,licnum=?,accdetails=?,fueltype=?,location=?,resperson=?,status=?,purchfrom=?,datepurch=?,price=?,quantity=?,fundsource=?,receipt=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->execute([$id,$name,$manufacturer,$model,$description,$type,$size,$consumable,$serialnum,$licnum,$accdetails,$fueltype,$location,$resperson,$status,$purchfrom,$datepurch,$price,$quantity,$fundsource,$receipt,$_GET['id']]);
header('Location: display.php?id='.$id);
$_SESSION['status'] = "The asset information has been successfully updated.";
```

Offending code

```
header('Location: display.php?id='.$id);
```

The script is working fine on other update / insert scripts fine on my system and was working fine on this page on Friday.

After looking on SO, I have found that it could be because it's on multiple lines but it's on a single line.

Comment: Have you test to display `'display.php?id='.$id` ...? To see on screen what it looks like....?

Comment: Thank you for this, I had not changed $company to $asset on the ID field. Working fine now, thanks Juan.